# Opacity issue in IE8 when Adding Simple Jquery Fadein/Fadeout

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-8, opacity

Iam trying to implement simple `JQuery Fadein/Fadeout` to my website. So i have done these steps

JQUERY

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {          
    $(".writereview").click(function(){

        $(".reviewpopup").fadeIn();
        $(".popupcontainer").fadeIn();

    });


    $(".popupclose").click(function(){

        $(".reviewpopup").fadeOut();
        $(".popupcontainer").fadeOut();

    });

    });

    </script>
```

HTML

```
   <div class="reviewpopup" style="display: none; "></div>
   <div class="popupcontainer" style="display: none; ">
   <iframe src="feedback.html" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="475" height="510">               </iframe>
    <a href="#" class="popupclose"><img src="images/popupclose.jpg" alt="HoHo"></a> </div>
```

CSS

```
.reviewpopup {

    display:none;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color:#000;
    opacity:0.5;
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)"; 
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);              
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    z-index:1001;   
        }

        .popupcontainer {
    width: auto;
    height:auto;
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top: 45px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -280px;
    background-color:#FFF;
    z-index:1001;
    border-radius:10px;
    -moz-border-radius:10px;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
    border:solid 5px #000;
    padding:20px;
         }
```

The **JQuery** is Working fine in all Browsers, But the Issue is, `Opacity is not working properly in IE8`. I just Removed the Jquery and it works. I don't know what is the exact reason with this **IE8 Opacity** and Jquery. Please Help me.

Comment: What happens if you remve `-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)"; `?

Comment: Define "Not working properly"

Comment: I used up all my points on a bounty or this would have been a comment versus answer.
The thing that often works better is animate opacity

Comment: @ben Not Working properly means : The Background is Pure Black. Not Semi Transparent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fadeIn()` overrides the CSS `filter` value, so when you call `fadeIn` on your partial-opacity element, you should reset the value in a callback:

```
var pop = $('.reviewpopup'),
    filter = pop.css('filter'); // fadeIn overrides filter value in IE8; reset it
pop.fadeIn(function() {
    if (filter) pop.css('filter', filter);
});
```